# How to force children rerendering after axios call in React?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm working on a form with interactive inputs. They have to actualise themselves with information into parent state.

I use Axios to get the data to show, getting them from an external API. I tried to set default values, but they never actualise with newer values.

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    getData() {
        axios.get('http://xxx/getform/').then(
            res => this.setState(res.data)
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
        setInterval(() => {
            this.getData();
        }, 36000000)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <DatePicker />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class DatePicker extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selected: new Date(),
            runMin: new Date(),
            runMax: new Date()
        };
    }

    getDate() {
        console.log('DAD');
        try { // if axios didn't finish, to avoid undefined
            this.setState({
                runMin: super.state.RunMin,
                runMax: super.state.RunMax})
        } catch (e) {
            this.setState({
                runMin: new Date(),
                runMax: new Date()})
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getDate();
        this.setState({selected: this.state.runMax});
    }

    render() {
        return (<div></div>);
    }
}
```

Actually after axios call, the children doesn't rerender. I separated the call for axios and the component using it, because the `Form` component do a single call for multiple children (not displayed here), and they read the parent's state to render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should not access the parents state using `super` and instead pass the required value as props

Secondly, componentDidMount lifecycle is executed on initial mount and hence the logic within it won't execute when the parent state updates.

The correct way to handle your case would be

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
    state = {
       RunMin: new Date(),
       RunMax: new Date()
    }
    getData() {
        axios.get('http://xxx/getform/').then(
            res => this.setState({RunMin: res.data.RunMin, RunMax: res.data.RunMax})
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
        setInterval(() => {
            this.getData();
        }, 36000000)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <DatePicker runMin={this.state.RunMin} runMax={this.state.RunMax}/>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class DatePicker extends React.Component {

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.runMin, this.props.runMax);
        return (<div></div>);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after manipulating with this idea, I found a way to do.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are setting the state is incorrect

Change

```
   this.setState(res.data);
```

To

```
 this.setState({data: res.data});
```

You need to set the response to a state field  you have in component and make sure you pass the data to the child component